# Not able to get ArgumentResolver working in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring 4.2.0.RELEASE and trying to use `WebArgumentResolver` but not able to understand the behavior for my case. There are two custom annotations that I have provided.

My controller has following mapping:

```java
@RequestMapping
public ModelAndView install(@AppFromId final App app, @JsonBody final Map postBody)
```

**MyArgumentResolver:**

```java
public class MyArgumentResolver implements WebArgumentResolver {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppArgumentResolver.class);

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter methodParameter, NativeWebRequest nativeWebRequest) throws Exception {

        String methodName = methodParameter.getMethod().getName();
        int parameterIndex = methodParameter.getParameterIndex();
        logger.info("Method-name: {}, parameter-index: {}, methodParamClass: {}", methodName, parameterIndex, methodParameter.getParameterType().getSimpleName());

        for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
            logger.info("Resolving annotation: {}", annotation.annotationType().getSimpleName());
        }

        return UNRESOLVED;
    }
}
```

Following is getting logged by `MyArgumentResolver` when I invoke the controller method:

> Method-name: installApp, parameter-index: 0, methodParamClass: App
>   Resolving annotation: AppFromId

**context.xml file**

```xml
<mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:argument-resolvers>
            <bean class="../MyArgumentResolver"/>
        </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

My question is, why the second parameter (`@JsonBoyd final Map postBody`) of the controller-method is not getting resolved/checked by `MyArgumentResolver`?

Comment: Can you try to return `new Object()` instead of `UNRESOLVED` to see if the second parameter will get logged this way?

Comment: @mzc The behavior is same